# Merging volumetric analysis into titration

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The [volumetric-analysis](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/volumetric-analysis) tag is used 11 times, while [titration](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/titration) is used 31 times. Surprisingly none of these questions are cross tagged.

I believe the two are synonyms, even wikipedia redirects [volumetric analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volumetric_analysis) to titration. So I would go for merging and keeping one of the others as synonym.

Comment: I agree. Remind me in a few days to merge this, if there is no opposition.

Comment: We can anticipate that the majority of students asking questions about titration will be relative beginners in chemistry. In such cases (at least in Britain!) the phrase 'titration' is far a more common term amongst such students than volumetric analysis. This may be different in other countries however. For my part, I suggest merging but keeping 'titration' as the mother tag.

Comment: @ManishEarth I guess more than two weeks without opposition shall serve as a good sign? I guess you can go for the merge now.

Comment: Merged. We may need to wait a while for the tag engine to update its cache.